# using POJO domain jar in Grails 3

Tags: grails-3.0, dependency-resolution

I'm trying to port a Grails 2.x project to Grails 3. The 2.x based project has domain made up of POJOs in a JAR but now v3 does not have a /lib directory any more and doc suggest the following:

> 4.7 Dependency Resolution

Dependency resolution is handled by the Gradle build tool, all dependencies are defined in the build.gradle file. Refer to the Gradle user guide for more information.

[(doc link)](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#dependencyResolution)

... can anyone offer a short-short version of how to handle adding a jar dependency (I have 0 familiarity with Gradle)

When I attempt running 'run-app' command it get this error (so at least the hibernate config file is being read):

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com.flightloglib.domain.AircraftMakeAndModel] declared in Hibernate configuration  entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directory for you jar, say `lib`.  Then

In the dependencies block of your `build.gradle`, create a compile time dependency on your jar.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/pojos.jar')
    // ...
}
```

The applicable docs are here: [Chapter 52](https://docs.gradle.org/2.7/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

... what I ended up doing is specifying the absolute path to my jar:

```
    dependencies {
...
compile files("/home/some-user-name-here/work/web/FlightLogGrails3/grails-app/lib/FlightLogLib.jar")
...
}
```

Comment: if you move your lib directory up to the project level (instead of in grails-app), I'd expect the relative path 'lib/FlightLogLib.jar' to work.  You could even make it a file set specification and get any jar you dropped in there added to the path.